# Facebook Share Dialog does not show the"tap To Change account" in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, facebook-share, fbsdksharedialog

I am using Facebook Sdk 4.38.0. I followed this document:
[Facebook Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android/)

I want to create an app that allows user to select `one page from the all of his Facebook pages` to share content, such as the `public page` or `business page`.

When run the app, although the user has a business page, he can not choose another page other than the public page. because `tap to cahnge` section not appear.

[image]

but in iOS, this is possible.

[image]

does anyone have a solution ?
Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Android is different from iOS

Comment: @Gourav Is there no way?

Comment: Nothing is impossible. I'm just pointing out that there is different way or both of them